# Not succeeding in using Toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying the following:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

box = tk.Toplevel()
box.title('My title')
tk.Message(box, text='My message').pack()
for i in range(100000000):
    pass
box.destroy()
```

When I issue these statements from the interactive interpreter, everything is fine and the message appears. However, the message does not appear when I run this as a script. What am I missing?

Comment: Call `root.mainloop()` before (actually, instead) of the silly `for` loop.

Comment: @DYZ I do not want to use the main loop of Tkinter. The for-loop is just for a simple test. As the question states, this works just fine in the interactive interpreter without the main loop.

Comment: The Interactive interpreter supplies it's own main loop.

Comment: @DYZ So, the main loop is a must if I want to use `Toplevel`?

Comment: Correct. Unless you go for the inefficient poor-man implementation of the main loop proposes in the answer.

Comment: The `mainloop` is a must if you want to use tkinter at all. Well, that's not 100% correct; you can repeatedly call `update`, though unless you really know what you're doing that could result in either a laggy GUI, or one that doesn't quite behave the way you expect.

Comment: @BryanOakley Unless all you use is tkMessageBox, I guess.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: on windows and osx that may be true. Certain widgets use the native OS event loop once they are up. Menus are one example, maybe the dialogs are another.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

box = tk.Toplevel()
box.title('My title')
tk.Message(box, text='My message').pack()
root.update() # this is the important line; may need it inside the loop
for i in range(100000000):
    pass
box.destroy()
```